# Populate cell with value from 3 possible cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to populate one cell based on the text value of one cell out of 5 possible choices. The other four cells will not have any values. Only one of the 5 will have a value I want to populate in the destination cell. How do I set up a formula to look in multiple cells, but only transfer the value from the cell with a value, ignoring the other 4 empty cells?

The cell with a value will change, and again, the other four cells will not have a value.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5)
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2010? My first thought is nested ifs. But since you said only one cell will have a text value and all others will not have values, then using `=CONCAT()` (or if concat is not available in 2010 version then `&` connector) should do it.